# Display text from database into 2 different divs

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to display text from a database row into 2 different divs.

The code currently selects all text from the row and displays both pieces of text in each div. Which isn't what I need. Is there a way to split the text, and have each text in its own div?

PHP:

```
//output each row
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo $row["content"];
}
```

HTML:

```
//Text box 1
<div>
    <p id="Text1">
        <?php echo $row["content"]; ?> 
    </p> 
</div>

//Text box 2
<div>
    <p id="Text2">
        <?php echo $row["content]; ?> 
    </p> 
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the relevant HTML inside the loop:

```
$i = 1; // For the id's
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
?>

    <div>
        <p id="Text<?= $i++; ?>">
            <?= $row["content"]; ?> 
        </p> 
    </div>

<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Do this
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $column1 .= '<p>'.$row["column1"].'</p>';
    $column2 .= '<p>'.$row["column2"].'</p>';
    $column3 .= '<p>'.$row["column3"].'</p>';
    $column4 .= '<p>'.$row["column4"].'</p>';
    //and so on...
}

//Column 1
<div id="column1">
     <?php echo $column1; ?>
</div>

//Column 2
<div id="column2">
     <?php echo $column2; ?>
</div>

//Column 3
<div id="column3">
     <?php echo $column3; ?>
</div>

//Column 4
<div id="column4">
     <?php echo $column4; ?>
</div>

//and so on...
```

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to have multiple columns per row. The OP seem to have one content column per row and wants that column to be in different divs.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought he specifically asked for the content in separate divs (.. "Is there a way to split the text, and have each text in its own div?")